# Kivy label left align and sizing

Tags: python, label, size, kivy

I have been running against this wall now for almost a day. I feel like I have tried everything. First here is what I want and what I have visually.

This what I have right now:

[image]

What I want is this:

[image]

In the images 'CurrentHistory:\nHeader:' is a single label. I can get it align left but I can't get it not have massive padding top and bottom. I's like the label is square and not a rectangle just around the text. I have been Kivy'ing now for about 2 days so please forgive me if I missed something super basic.

**EDIT**

I updated with a fully functional demo. The odd thing is that the .kv produced label does exactly what I want it to do, but the Label produced via python does not.

The SegmentLayout is identical to the GridLayout defined in the .kv file :(

The overall layout is this: .kv

```
#:kivy 1.8.0

<MainWidget>
    BoxLayout
        size: root.size

        ScrollView
            id: scrlv
            size_hint: .75, 1

            GridLayout
                cols: 1
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: max(self.minimum_height, scrlv.height)

                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 150/255, 150/255, 150/255, 1
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size

                SegmentLayout

                GridLayout
                    cols: 1
                    size_hint: 1,None
                    height: self.minimum_height

                    Label
                        text: '[b]CurrentHistory:[/b]\nHeader:'
                        size_hint: (None, None)
                        halign: 'left'
                        markup: True
                        size: self.texture_size

                    TextInput
                        size_hint: (1,None)
                        height: self.minimum_height
                        text: 'Enter Text Here'

        BoxLayout
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint: .25, 1

            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 240/255, 180/255, 80/255, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            Label
                text: "Label 1"
            Label
                text: "Label 2"
```

python driver demo

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.8.0') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.factory import Factory

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class SegmentLayout(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SegmentLayout, self).__init__(cols=1, size_hint=(1,None), **kwargs)
        self.bind(minimum_height=self.setter('height'))

        label_text = '[b]CurrentHistory:[/b]\nHeader:'

        label = Label(text=label_text, halign='left', size_hint=(None,None), markup=True)
        label.bind(size=label.setter('texture_size'))    
        self.add_widget(label)

        text_input = TextInput(text='Enter Text Here', size_hint=(1,None))
        text_input.bind(minimum_height=text_input.setter('height'))
        self.add_widget(text_input)

class MainWidget(Widget):
    pass

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainWidget()

Factory.register('SegmentLayout', cls=SegmentLayout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: I added a fully functional Demo, the odd thing is that when making what I want in the simple .kv file it works as expected, when doing it via python it fails. The .kv file does what I would expect to happen.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following link https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.halign which warns against using the halign Property. My solution without halign is as follows:

```
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: sized_label.height
                Label:
                    id: sized_label
                    text: "[b]CurrentHistory:[/b]\\nHeader:"
                    size_hint: (None, None)
                    markup: True
                    size: self.texture_size
                Label:
```

I am placing a Label with your text in a BoxLayout. I set the size height to the size of the label with text. The label with text is sized to have the size of its text. Since the label with text is not as wide as the BoxLayout I use another Label just to fill the empty space.

Here is your updated code. I put it all in the .py file, since you said in the comments you were struggling with that. There was also a lot of code which I erased, because it was double or not neccessary. I hope now it is easier for you to continue working with that. I also used stuff like text_hint for your TextInput. If you do not want that it should be easy to revert those changes...

Here is my updated code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.factory import Factory

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from kivy.base import Builder

kv_string = Builder.load_string("""
BoxLayout:
    BoxLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 150/255, 150/255, 150/255, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        ScrollView:
            id: scrlv

            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                size_hint_y: None
                height: max(self.minimum_height, scrlv.height)

                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: sized_label.height
                    Label:
                        id: sized_label
                        text: "[b]CurrentHistory:[/b]\\nHeader:"
                        size_hint: (None, None)
                        markup: True
                        size: self.texture_size
                    Label:

                TextInput:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: 80
                    hint_text: 'Enter Text Here'
                Label:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint_x: .25

        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 240/255, 180/255, 80/255, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        Label:
            text: "Label 1"
        Label:
            text: "Label 2"
""")



class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return kv_string



if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is not so much that I can't get the label to work as I want, but that doing via the kv file gives the results I want while doing it via python does not. In my demo files, SegmentLayout is identical to the grid layout sister defined in the kv file. The only difference is that SegmentLayout is defined in python vs in the kv file.

Comment: I add the SegmentLayout in the kv file I posted. When I edited the question I literally copied my python file and my kv file into the original post. Where am I missing the ':'? The demo I provided shows that the segment layout is behaving differently than the exact same kv defined structure and I am confused as to why